# Google Apps Script: Get rows from spreadsheet and post as formatted list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I have a Spreadsheet with only one column and a rows of names:

[Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTvmg.png)

Using Google Apps Script, I have made a telegram bot with multiple functions - and as one of those functions I want the bot to post the content of this sheet as a list.

I can easily pull the rows as an array using:

```
function sendlist() {
  var rows = SpreadsheetApp.openById(neueliste).getSheetByName('Liste').getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(rows);
}
```

giving me

[Rows Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YslLw.png)

Now, my question is, **how can I post this array as a formatted "list"**, in the style of

- Entry 1
- Entry 2
- Entry 3

?

Adding names to the list isn't a problem, I am using this for that:

```
 if ((text.startsWith('/addlist')) {
      var sheetName = "Liste";
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName(sheetName) : SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).insertSheet(sheetName);
      var args = text.split(" ");
      var arg1 = args[1];
      sheet.appendRow([name,arg1]);
      sendText(id,"Hello " + name + " your name '" + arg1 + "' has been added.");
    }
```

Works like a treat. **But I can't wrap my head around how to do the `sendText(id, [...])` to post the content of rows as a formatted list.**

Any help?

I looked at using the forEach function, but that didnt get me anywhere so far.

Answer (score 0):

And managed it a bit later:

```
var rows = SpreadsheetApp.openById(neueliste).getSheetByName('Liste').getDataRange().getValues();
var arrayLength = rows.length;
var liststring;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  if(i = 0){
    liststring = rows[i];
  } else {
    liststring = liststring + "\n" + rows[i];
  }
}
sendText(id, liststring);
```

Works perfectly :)